# How convert column datatype int64 to categorical column datatype in python?

Tags: python, pandas, types, type-conversion, multiclass-classification

how can i change int to categorical

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx',header=0)
data.info()
```

there is now a column damage which is int64. It shows different damage-groups. How can this column be convert to a categorical column? (background is, there are 4 damage groups. 1 not really damage, 4 is totally damage).

I tried:

```
data['damage']= data.damage.astype('categorical')

*data type 'categorical' not understood*
```

but it doesn´t work. This works for example with ('float') or anything else.
How can the column damage transfer to a categorical column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html) categorical `Series` or columns in a `DataFrame` can be created by several ways. One way is converting an existing `Series` or column to a `category` dtype.
So change:

```
data['damage']= data.damage.astype('categorical')
```

To:

```
data['damage'] = data.damage.astype('category')
```